# animation for the red box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can any one make this red box smooth animated with jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trapezoid-two").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('path').attr('d','M0,0 L100,23 L100,80 L0,100z');
    });
});
```

Here's an example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93e9yguc/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any JS code for this; you can use two `<animate>` tags, one for `mouseenter` and the other for `mouseleave`. Try this:

```
<path d="M0,0 L100,23 L100,77 L0,100z" fill="red">
    <animate begin="mouseenter" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" to="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100z" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate begin="mouseleave" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" to="M0,0 L100,23 L100,77 L0,100z" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
</path>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/93e9yguc/1/)

Comment: yes, this is ok, but my problem is when any one over the big box then inside this red box is animate.